# Random Image with Random Links

Tags: javascript, html, random

```
<html>
<body>
<script>

var images_src = ["PrizeImage-1","PrizeImage-2","PrizeImage-3",];
var links = ["Participate1","Participate2","Participate3","Participate4",];

</script>
<a href="random_link" ><img src='random_img' alt='image'></a>
</body>
</html>
```

how can I call random links with random image in a single HTML page

Comment: You will need to be more descriptive with what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried.

Comment: I have single HTML Page and there are hundres of images and links. I want to show random pic with random link in a single HTML page

Comment: Are the links coming from json, are they in an array variable on the page, are they one giant string? Do the image tags already exist, what css is on them? When are you doing this mapping, can the user change it? What javascript have you tried? And thats just a start of the details you will need to provide, otherwise your question is to vague and against stacks guidelines.

Comment: I have updated codes please check @Blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the image and link with random values you can do it like this:

HTML

```
<a href="random_link" id="linkEl"><img id='imgEl' src='random_img' alt='image'></a>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var Links = ["Link1" , "Link2" , "Link3" , "Link4"];
var images_src = ["Image1" , "Image3" , "Image3" , "Image4"];

var randomLink = Links[parseInt(Math.random()*Links.length)]; //Get random link (with random number from 0 to the link array's length
var randomImage= images_src[parseInt(Math.random()*images_src.length)];//Get random image
var linkEl = document.getElementById('linkEl'); //Get link element
var imgEl = document.getElementById('imgEl'); //Get image eement

linkEl.href = randomLink; //Set the link
imgEl.src = randomImage; //Set the image
```

For more funcionality, you should provide more detail, but this might get you going hopefully.

**--- EDIT ---**

To reuse the code for more than one image, place it in a function

```
var Links = ["Link1" , "Link2" , "Link3" , "Link4"];
var images_src = ["Image1" , "Image3" , "Image3" , "Image4"];

function fillRandom(imageId, linkId) {
    var randomLink = Links[parseInt(Math.random()*Links.length)]; //Get random link (with random number from 0 to the link array's length
    var randomImage= images_src[parseInt(Math.random()*images_src.length)];//Get random image
    var linkEl = document.getElementById(linkId); //Get link element
    var imgEl = document.getElementById(imageId); //Get image eement

    linkEl.href = randomLink; //Set the link
    imgEl.src = randomImage; //Set the image
}
```

And then call the function as many times as the images you have:

```
fillRandom('imageId', 'linkId');
fillRandom('secondImageId', 'secondLinkId');
```

Comment: `<html>
<body>
<script>

var images_src = ["PrizeImage-1","PrizeImage-2","PrizeImage-3",];
var links = ["Participate1","Participate2","Participate3","Participate4",];

</script>
<a href="random_link" ><img src='random_img' alt='image'></a>
</body>
</html>`
Images source are the external links as well as Links are also external links

Comment: What do you mean by external? 
The solution I presented selects a random image and link from the arrays. If you have another source either convert it to an array first and use the solution above, or provide more information on the external source concrete case.

Comment: updated my quesiton please recheck and guide me please

Comment: When you edit your questions, please add an edit section below, instead of replacing values - this way it will be clearer what you changed.
In this case you changed only the strings for the links and images? As far as the code goes, what the strings are is irrelevant. The code is going to generate a random number and pick that position from the array.

Comment: @EhsanQureshi, there's nothing "external" in your provided code/explanation. Please be more specific about what you want, and what exactly you already have, and what your actual problem is.

Comment: Sorry for confusion Sir. I am just trying to get solution for my this small script. as I am totally newbie I have just create a fiddle sample to make you understand . https://jsfiddle.net/tf8cgb6r/1/

Comment: The solution would work with external links for images.

Comment: If this really is some lottery/contest where sbd. can win something, please contact some serious developer to implement that for you. You can make so many mistakes with such things, and you are liable for that.

Comment: Bundle of thanks Sir @JoaoQuental  .. its working great fine..  (with due Respect)

Comment: @Thomas .. Sir this is small lottery I am operating in my town. So i decided to make it computerized draw. Thanks for giving such a brilliant solutions

Comment: can I annouce 2 or more in a single page. but I think cannot with ID element . please can you please also help me to make it 2 or more image in a singel page @JoaoQuental

Comment: See the Edit on the answer. Would it work for you? What do you mean by "I think cannot with ID element"?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tf8cgb6r/2/ please check This I have checked here but didnt work for me please update it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tf8cgb6r/3/  Here's the code. You should note that you were missing the function closing bracket and the calls for the function itself.